# Files.newDirectoryStream() throws AccessDeniedException on root in Windows XP

Tags: java, windows-xp, java-7, access-denied

I wrote the following code:

```
void backupFileAttributes(Path path, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        if (Files.isReadable(path))
        {
            DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
            for (Path entry : stream)
            {
                BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(entry, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                if (Files.isDirectory(entry))
                {
                    writer.append((getFileData(entry, attr)));
                    writer.newLine();
                    backupFileAttributes(entry, writer);
                }
                writer.append(getFileData(entry, attr));
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Could not read directory: " + path.toAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Access was denied on path: " + path.toAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

However, the line

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
```

Throws AccessDeniedException on Windows XP when used on `C:\`. I need Java 7 utilities using Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java-6 for accessing the files, then use the Java-7 specific features using `file.toPath()`.

```
void backupFileAttributes(File dir, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        String[] files = dir.list();
        if (files != null)
        {
            for (String s : files)
            {
                String path;
                if (s.equals(".") == true)
                {
                    path = s;
                }
                else
                {
                    path = dir.getPath() + File.separator + s;
                }

                File f = new File(path);
                if (f.canRead() != false)
                {
                    Path p = f.toPath();
                    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                    if (f.isDirectory() == true)
                    {
                        writer.append((getFileData(p, attr)));
                        writer.newLine();
                        backupFileAttributes(f, writer);
                    }
                    else if (f.isFile() == true)
                    {
                        writer.append(getFileData(p, attr));
                        writer.newLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Access was denied on path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```